# How does this Python graph / tree traversal work?

Tags: python

```
def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    if not graph.has_key(start):
        return []
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            for newpath in newpaths:
                paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```

I cannot understand the recursive part of this function. I've been looking at it for a few hours now but it is still very confusing to me. Would someone be able to explain this function in a ELI5 way? Thanks

Comment: This is a fairly straight forwards recursive depth-first search. Do you understand the `graph`s at all? Recursion? I'm not sure Stack Overflow is going to be able to teach you even basic graph algorithms if you don't know anything yourself.

Comment: You can start by fixing the `path=[]` mutable default parameter.  It's never correct, and it makes tracing recursive calls especially difficult.  (See the "Important Warning" in _The Python Tutorial_'s section about [Default Argument Parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase: No, the mutable default is fine here, it's always being copied on the first line of the function, never modified in place.

Comment: @Blckknght  It doesn't happen to cause an observable bug now, but it's a landmine waiting for some well-meaning refactoring to set it off.  ("Why copy all that data?  Isn't this why lists have an `extend` method?")  I'd dispose of it like any other unexploded ordnance found lying around.  If nothing else, someone trying to learn how and why the function works doesn't need the added burden of ruling out the mutable default argument as a source of surprising test results.

Comment: In any recursive algorithm that keeps track of paths like this, you'll need to copy the path at some point or the results will all be references to the last path. If you used backtracking you could put off the copying until the `start == end` base case, but it can be simpler to make a copy at each step and skip the backtracking. Once you're copying `path` rather than mutating it in place, it doesn't hurt to give it a mutable default value. I think a "be careful about using mutable default arguments" comment would have been entirely appropriate, but saying it needs to be fixed is just wrong.

Comment: @Blckknght  You are right --- I did overstate the case by saying it's "never correct".  While researching my reply, I found examples of [valid uses for mutable defaults](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm#valid-uses-for-mutable-defaults) in Fredrik Lundh's "[Default Parameter Values in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)".  I don't _like_ those uses, but they're hardly "incorrect".  So thank you for that discovery.  [And with this comment, I have completely divorced our conversation from Kevin Li's original question.  Time for me to stop.]